# Adding Swipe to Refresh Layout for Dynamic list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

In my app, there is a list of assign route. Route has been assigned from web. List has been updated after pull down in the view. But, everytime i pull down, view get expand.

This is my screenshot before applying swipe to refresh:

[image]

This is my screenshot after applying swipe to refresh:

[image]

View get expand continously everytime after pull down the view for swipe to refresh.

This is how I include the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.RoutesAssignActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefreshLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Api call:

```
void getRoutes() {

    Log.e("getRoutes", "=======getRoutes======== ");



    final ApiService service = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<ApiResponse> signedIn = service.getRoutesApi(getPreference().getToken());
    signedIn.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ApiResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                ApiResponse result = response.body();

                //error handling
                if (result.getData() != null && result.getData().getRoutesList() != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    emptyHistory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    historyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    routesDatas = result.getData().getRoutesList();
                    setupRecyclerView(routesDatas);
                } else if (result.getMsg().equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid token or Token has expired")) {
                    getPreference().removeLoginPreferences();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RoutesAssignActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    emptyHistory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    historyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                // response received but request not successful (like 400,401,403 etc)
                //Handle errors
                dialog.dismiss();
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        response.message(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            showNetworkSettings();
            Log.e("Errors :: getRoutes", "=======Status Code ======== " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Assign route get update here: `routesDatas = result.getData().getRoutesList();`

At `onCreate` method, I call the `getRoutes()` method:

```
if (getNetworkStatus()) {
        getRoutes();
    } else {
        showNetworkSettings();
    }
```

I setup the `RecyclerView` as:

```
void setupRecyclerView(List<RoutesList> routes) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    FontIconTypefaceHolder.init(getAssets(), "fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf");

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    stickyHeaderListAdapter = new StickyHeaderListAdapter(routes, this);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this).build());
    final StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration headersDecor = new StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration(stickyHeaderListAdapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(headersDecor);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(stickyHeaderListAdapter);
}
```

I apply `Swipe to Refresh` at `onCreate` method, so the view get expand continously everytime when I pull down.

```
if (getNetworkStatus()) {
        getRoutes();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                getRoutes();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
        showNetworkSettings();
    }
```

How do I implement the `Swipe to Refresh` here ?

Comment: Do not set the recyclerView everytime you refresh, just create a method in adapter for setting items and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` is not required since your item size may vary. And in your layout use `match_parent` as height for every widget.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion, i will remove that. You mean, I use `notifyDataSetChanged` in `setupRecyclerView` method.

Comment: Here, view get expand only, when i apply  `pull down to refresh` at list screen. But, when I go from home screen to list screen, view seems fine.

Comment: yes or else you can create a method named `updateListAdapter()` where you can set Items and notify adapter and `setupRecyclerView()` can be called only once in oncreate with empty list.

Comment: have you tried `match_parent` as height for both RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: Yes, i already tried that but it doesn't work. View get expand when pull down.

Comment: What about RecyclerView version you are using?

Comment: The problem is setting adapter on refresh, change it as i said before and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Okay, let me check. Or can you please provide few code lines to help me.

Comment: Check my edited answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set the adapter to **RecyclerView** everytime you refresh, just create a method in **adapter** for setting items in **adapter** and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. One more thing is  `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` is not required since your item size may vary. Also in your layout use `match_parent` as height for every widget.
 Like :

In `onCreate()` before calling your API, call `setupRecyclerView(new ArrayList<RoutesList>());` which is an empty list.

In your **Apapter** create a method like

```
public void setItemsAndUpdateList(ArrayList<RoutesList> routes) {
    //clear your old list
    your_list.clear();
    //Add all new Items
    your_list.addAll(routes);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your `getRoutes()` instead of calling `setupRecyclerView(routesDatas);`, call `adapter.setItemsAndUpdateList(routesData);`.

Comment: `ADAPTER` mean my `Adapter Class`. I upvote this for clear explain and effort.

Comment: Yes your adapter class